# Почему навигационная модель спадает вниз к блоку main при использовании position: fixed;

Tags: html, css

```css
.nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: fixed;
  transition: all 0.8s ease 0s;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.nav-color {
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  opacity: 0.9;
  transition: all 0.8s ease 0s;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="page">
    <header>
      <div class="nav">
        <div class="logo">
          <a href="#"> <img src="/static/articles/img/logo.png" alt="лого">
            <span>RuArticles</span> </a>
        </div>
        <ul class="menu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Новинки</a>
          </li>
          <li> <a href="#">Темы</a></li>
          <a href="#">
          </a>
        </ul>
        <a href="#">
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-white btn-nav"><img src="/static/articles/img/pencil.png" alt="карандаш"><span>Написать пост</span></a>
        <div class="reg"><img src="/static/articles/img/user.png" class="photo-user" alt="иконка пользователя"><span>Войти</span></div>
      </div>

    </header>
    <main>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="popular">
          <h3 class="popular-text">Популярные</h3>
          <hr class="popular-line">
        </div>

        <div class="filter">
          <a href="/articles/" class="btn-grey" style="margin-right: -6px;">Все потоки</a>
          <a href="/articles/filter/1" class="btn-grey" style="border-radius: 0; margin-right: -6px;">Новое</a>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button onclick="myFunction()" class="btn-grey dropbtn" style="border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;">Лучшее
        </button>
            <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="/articles/filter/2">За неделю</a>
              <a href="/articles/filter/3">За месяц</a>
              <a href="/articles/filter/4" style="margin-bottom: 19px;">За всё время</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>



        <div class="block-article">
          <div class="article-inner">
            <a href="/articles/16/" style="display: inherit;">


            </a>
            <div class="article-main">
              <a href="/articles/16/" style="display: inherit;">
                <div class="article-text">
                  <div class="article-name">asdfasd</div>
                  <div class="article-main-text">dasfasdfasdf
                  </div>
                </div>
              </a>
```

[image: в]
Если я убираю fixed всё возращается
[image: в]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что свойство `fixed` так и должно работать: элемент, которому задано такое позиционирование располагается фиксировано относительно окна браузера, а все остальные элементы страницы размещаются, словно его не существует.

Поэтому элемент `fixed`, как бы, "висит" над всем содержимым страницы.

Конкретно в Вашем случае при заданном свойстве `fixed`, `header` становится нулевой высоты и `main` перемещается наверх и попадает под навигационную панель.

Вы также можете ознакомится с работой `position: fixed` по [ссылке](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/position)